# complex conjugate of Bessel function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

This is probably a simple question, however, how does one take a complex conjugate of the Bessel function,$$
J_1(z),\quad 
z\in \mathbb{C}$$
I am asking because I am interested in calculating
$$
|J_1(z)|^2=J_1(z)\cdot {\bar{J_1}}(z)
$$
where the bar above $J_1$ denotes complex conjugation. 
In general for a complex number we can write
$$
z=x+iy,\quad \bar{z}=x-iy
$$
If you're wondering why this is relevant, well for example, an integral of the form
$$
\int z J^2_1(z)dz=\frac{1}{2}z^2 (J^2_1(z)-J_0(z)J_2(z))
$$
only when $z\in \mathbb{R}$ 
however , I am interested in calculating
$$
\int z |J_1(z)|^2 dz
$$
when $z\in \mathbb{C}$,
where $|J_1(z)|^2=\bar{J}_1\cdot J_1$. (if anybody knows how to do this integral, feel free to let me know as well).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a holomorphic function $f$ maps reals to reals, then it satisfies the equality $\overline{f(z)} = f(\overline z)$.

Comment: thank you very much for the clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Paley-Wiener Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), the Bessel functions $J_n(t)$ are entire functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since they are the inverse Fourier transforms of compact-supported, even real functions. By the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) it follows that:
$$ \overline{J_n(z)} = J_n(\overline{z}).$$

Comment: thank you very much.  That's very helpful and interesting!

Answer (score 0):

As for the integral, notice the integrand $z|J_1(z)|^2$ is an odd function in $z$. Hence the integral vanishes when integrated over a finite region with the appropriate symmetry. However the integral over all $z \in \mathbb C$ is divergent.